# what are these kind of graphs called in graph theory ?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose the graph $G$ (here, we assume this graph is self-looped, i.e., each vertex is connected to itself) satisfies the following condition. For each vertex $v$ in $V(G)$, there is another vertex $u$ such that $u\neq v$, $uv$ is an edge in $G$, and $u$'s neighborhood contains $v$'s neighborhood. Is there any specific kind of graph similar to this in graph theory on which people usually do research? Any reference to the similar concepts would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Could you give us some context, for example, where this question comes from?

Comment: I got this from some experimental data sets (need to double check). I hope this is not my imagination.

Comment: Surely if each vertex v has a neighbour w such that N[v] contains N[w] then the neighbourhood of every vertex contains the neighbourhood of every other one. This only allows for complete graphs, right?

Comment: I did  not get it. Why is that ?

Comment: So, firstly by N[v] I mean the neighbourhood of v. Then, you seem to be saying that for some vertex v, we have a vertex w such that N[w] contains N[v]. Since this is symmetric, N[v] must also contain N[w] - so they must be equal! Another way to say it is that every vertex has all the other vertices as neighbours - which is only true for complete graphs. I think that's correct...

Comment: Oh, and it might help if you give an example of one of your graphs (looking at your profile, I assume it would be from biological data?) that might help.

Comment: @gilleain, I did not get it about your reasoning. How do you know that this is symmetric. I do not think that you can deduce that N[v] must contain N[w].

Comment: @gilleain, maybe you are right. In the data, that is a bit relaxation of the kind of graph I mentioned here. Because in the graph generated from the data, there is exactly one vertex, say vertex $u$ which does not have a neighbor whose neighborhood contains $u$'s neighborhood. I just did not see where does the being symmetric come from?

Comment: @nstrong because you say "For each vertex v" - so I can just swap v and w? REally a drawing of an example without the biological labels might help. Presumably it's protein interaction networks or something.

Comment: @gilleain, when you consider the vertex $w$, you can deduce that there is another vertex $u$, such that $u$'s neighborhood contains $w$'s neighborhood, but how do you know that $u$ is the same as the vertex $v$? Are you doing this for a number of times? And then since the number of vertices are finite, then it must goes back to some vertex which has already been visited? If so, I agree with you.

Comment: @gilleain, complete graph surely satisfies this condition. I really do not have other examples with this property in my head currently. All the examples are a bit relaxed with one vertex exception.

Answer (score 0):

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is rather interesting because your graph has loops and unless I misunderstood, each vertex shares the same neighborhood. This appears to be a complete graph, however complete graphs do not have loops and therefore it doesn't appear to be that your suggested graph is a complete graph.

However, if the given graph $G$ has loops $given$ or $implied$ by the question, so to speak (apologies if this doesn't make sense), meaning that the neighborhood of each vertex includes itself, then I would assume that a complete graph would be appropriate. This is because, say we had a graph $G$ with a set $V$ of vertices {$u, v, w, x, y$}, effectively $G({\{u, v, w, x, y}\}, E)$, then the neighborhood of each node in this "pseudo"-complete graph would contain all the vertices. For example $N[v]$ = {$v, u, w, x, y$}. This would apply to the neighborhoods of all the nodes and satisfies the condition that $u \neq v$ for all nodes in the problem.